# Intersect method does not appear to work with a Data Entry Form

Tags: forms, methods, intersect

The following code works as expected when I enter data directly into the worksheet. However, when I enter data using a form the code does not work. What am I missing here?

```
Set KeyCells = Range("UpdatedRange")
```

If Not Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
Is Nothing Then

```
    Range("AE" & Target.Row & "") = Now
```

End If

End Sub

I expected the code to work with a form as well as when entering data directly into the worksheet